# Google FAQ schema not showing (multiple schema in same page)

Tags: schema, schema.org, markup

So this is my URL https://www.rosterelf.com/pricing.

And if you go to page source, I have added 2 Schemas `Product` and `FAQPage`.

Then I went to https://search.google.com/test/rich-results and pasted my URL to test the schema and it gives me no error.

Then I went to Google and pasted this in search `site:https://www.rosterelf.com/pricing` but it only gives me review schema in result. My FAQ schema is not showing.

[image]

Can someone guide me why its not showing ? Is it because I have added multiple times `<script type="application/ld+json">` for both the schemas ? Or any other reason ?

Please Guide me how can I solve this ?

Thanks for any feedback or suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

The content of your website mentions the legal name RosterElf Pty Ltd in the footer. There is no information in the content about the name's connection to your website, and there is no easily verifiable confirmation of the name's legitimacy. In the content of your website, I did not find comprehensive information about the business behind the website, including information about legitimacy. Thus, the content of your website represents an unidentified business and an unidentified publisher. These are signals of low trustworthiness of the content.

In the guide [FAQ (FAQPage, Question, Answer) structured data](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/appearance/structured-data/faqpage?hl=en) Google tells us:

> Update on August 8, 2023: FAQ rich results are only shown in the
> Search results for a limited number of well-known, authoritative
> government and health websites.

Google probably considers your unreliable content as little-known.

Comment: Thanks for your inputs. So what can I do in my code to be able to show it ? Will it not been shown based on new rules ?

Comment: Try using the Stanford Guidelines for Web Credibility https://credibility.stanford.edu/guidelines/index.html and/or Search Quality Evaluator Guidelines https://static.googleusercontent.com/media/www.google.com/en//insidesearch/howsearchworks/assets/searchqualityevaluatorguidelines.pdf

Comment: You can find some useful thoughts in my article Ways to create trustworthy content https://nikantmark.com/artcl/trstw.html